# Cancel a WebClient FTP upload already uploading

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

Is it possible to do this?...

```
WebClient client;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_UploadProgressChanged);
  client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadFileCompleted);

  //Start the upload
  client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("/targetfile.jpg"), @"c:\sourcefile.jpg");
}

private void client_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  //upload finished
}

private void client_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ProgressPercentage == 60)
  {
    //Cancel the upload
    client.CancelAsync();
  }

  //update progressbar
}
```

As soon as I try to cancel the upload with CancelAsync() I find that my app terminates (with no exceptions or errors...  Just closes when I have it running from the IDE.) yet the file continues to upload to the FTP site (I can see it monitoring the FTP site).

Side note...  When I run it as a compiled application it also crashes with no error of any type but checking the system logs under Application I get a .Net Runtime error...

```
Application: MyUploader.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.WebException
Stack:
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(System.Net.CloseExState)
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Dispose(Boolean)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.Net.WebClient+UploadBitsState.Close()
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadBitsWriteCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

Ideas?

Comment: Let's first figure out what you are trying to accomplish.  As it stands, you are using asynchronous methods while simultaneously "waiting" on the main thread.  This indicates ambiguity on whether you want to achieve synchronous or asynchronous behavior.  Waiting via the `while` loop accomplishes the former, using the async methods of `WebClient` accomplishes the latter.  It makes no sense to mix these two concepts, so regardless of why exactly you're getting the error, you should resolve this question first.

Comment: Sorry Kirk, I updated the question a little to clear things up.
Does it look a little better?